# RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#622c4 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am New to Flutter
I am Fetching and Displaying Data on Screen, I have 2 ListView coming data from api, I am using Future Builder.
I can't place two FutureBuilder in a Container I have to use this error occur

```
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#622c4 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
```

Here's My Code

```
Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            FutureBuilder <List<Users>>(
            future: users,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                print('True');
                List<Users> data = snapshot.data!;
                return 
                  ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 1,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    var family = data[index].mobile;
                    var family_id = data[index].family_id;
                    return Card(
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(padding:EdgeInsets.all(10)),
                          ListTile(
                            title: Text(family),
                            subtitle: Text('Id:$family_id'),
                          ),
                        Padding(padding:EdgeInsets.all(10)),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                );
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text("${snapshot.error}");
              }else{
                return Container(child: Text('Null'),);
              }
            }
            ),
            FutureBuilder <List<FamilyMembers>>(
            future: futureData,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                List<FamilyMembers> data = snapshot.data!;
                return 
                  ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    var name = data[index].name;
                    var age = data[index].age;
                    return Card(
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(padding:EdgeInsets.all(10)),
                          ListTile(
                            title: Text(data[index].name),
                            subtitle: Text('Name:$name \nAge:$age'),
                          ),
                        Padding(padding:EdgeInsets.all(10)),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                );
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text("${snapshot.error}");
              }else{
                return Container();
              }
            }
            )

      ]
      )
```

I am trying to solve this error but this issue comes with every change.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list needs a height and a width in order to render try wrapping the FutureBuilder in Expanded or wrapping it with a Container with specific height and width you want your list to have. (Relevant for both lists)

Try this and tell me if it works :)